# Where can I find CSS Locator Reference?

Tags: css, w3c

Where can I find a complete official reference of CSS Locators?

Thanks

Comment: did you mean Selenium CSS Locators?

Comment: No .. Css selectors. Its the same thing as Selenium css locators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean CSS *selectors*?

CSS2: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

CSS3 (subject to change): http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference) is also a good reference.